# Passing data from one page to another page WPF VB.Net

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have two `WPF` pages open, and I want to send "textbox3.text" from Page2 to "textbox1.text" in Page1

in vb that's easy:

```
page1.textbox1.text = texbox3.text
```

but I can't find out how to do that in WPF

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a property in Page1 contains the value which in the TextBox

```
Public ReadOnly Property TextBox1Value() As String
    Get
        Return theFirstTextBox.Text
    End Get
End Property
```

And get this value and pass it to the Page2 in the Constructor for example

```
Public Sub New(ByVal value As String)

    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    theSecondTextBox.Text = value
End Sub

Private Sub CreatePage2Method()
    Dim page As Page2 = New Page2("BlaBlaBla")
    NavigationService.Navigate(page)
End Sub
```

Good luck!